# Define a differential $1$-form on the cylinder which is closed but not exact.

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Problem: Define a differential $1$-form on the cylinder $$C = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 = 1 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^3 $$ which is closed but not exact.

**My attempt (EDITED):**

I am using $\omega = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} (xdy - ydx) \in \Omega^1 (C)$. I showed that $\omega$ is closed by working out $d\omega = 0 $. My question is based on how to show that $\omega$ is not exact.

One sufficient condition that I know is that closed forms are exact if and only if the integral is zero if and only if the form vanishes at some point. However, this raises a few questions: How can I integrate over $C$ if it is not bounded? Furthermore, $C$ seems to be a two-dimensional manifold so integrating a $1$-form over $C$ doesn't seem to make quite sense.

Maybe the thing that makes more sense is to integrate over the curve, which I can choose to be $S^1 = \{ (x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$ because $\omega$ is a $1$-form so we can integrate around a curve that lives in $C$? (please correct me if I am wrong, this idea is not quite solidified for me)

So then by Stokes': $$\int_{S^1} \omega = \int_{S^1} xdy - ydx = \int_{D^2} d(xdy - ydx) = 2 \int_{D^2} dx \wedge dy = 2 \cdot \mathrm{vol}(D^2) = 2\pi$$ Can I integrate over $D^2$ even though the interior of $D^2$ does not intersect with $C$?

This implies that $\omega|_{S^1} \in \Omega^1(S^1)$ is a closed but not exact form. Consider the canonical projection map $\pi:C \rightarrow S^1$. Maybe there is some condition on $\pi$ such that $\pi^*(\omega|_{S^1}) = \omega \in \Omega^1(C)$ pullback to a closed but not exact $1$-form?

Thank you.

Comment: You do not need to invoke Stoke's theorem to integrate $\omega$ around $S^1$. You should be able to explicitly calculate the integral by hand.

Comment: it is enough to show that there is some closed path $\gamma$ in $C$ such that $\int_{\gamma }\omega \neq 0$, then $\omega$ can't be exact (indeed in you chosen $\omega$ you have that $x^2+y^2=1$ in $C$ so $\omega =x\,d y-y\,d x$)

Comment: @Masacroso It feels necessary to have the $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ factor in $\omega$ even though $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, otherwise $d(xdy - ydx) = 2 dx \wedge dy \neq 0$ which means it isn't closed...?

Comment: @mathlover314 if $x^2+y^2=1$ then $2xdx=-2ydy \Rightarrow  dx=-\tfrac{y}{x}dy$ when $x\neq 0$, then substituting you have that $dx\wedge dy=-\tfrac{y}{x}dy\wedge dy=0$ when $x\neq 0$, and in general it can be shown that $dx\wedge dy=0$ also when $x=0$ (just use the other subtitution when $y\neq 0$), so $d\omega =0$

Comment: indeed its easier to see what form have $\omega$ using polar coordinates, then $\omega =\cos \theta\, d(\sin \theta )-\sin \theta\, d(\cos \theta )=d\theta $, so $\omega $ is closed but not exact, as any closed path $\gamma$ surrounding the cylinder once will give $\int_{\gamma }\omega =2\pi\neq 0$

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Thank you, I worked out the explicit integral by hand and it works. One question, was I allowed to use Stokes' theorem? The original $\omega$ has a factor of $\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$ which isn't defined on $(x,y) = (0,0) \in D^2$. However, once I restrict it to $S^1$ that factor "disappears".

Comment: @Masacroso I read Lee Corollary 16.15. to figure out why that works. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding Stokes: For the original $\omega=\frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}$ you cannot use Stokes because this $\omega$ has a singularity. You did  in fact use another $\omega=x\,dy-y\,dx$ which has no singularity and agrees with the original on $S^1\,.$ That's no problem and the integrals are correct. In fact it strikes me as a smart way of doing it. BTW the original form has $d\omega=0$ and yours has, as you wrote, $d\omega=2\,dx\wedge dy\,.$ The fact that the original $d\omega$ is zero and the line integral is not zero is the reason why Stokes cannot be used with that.